# % operation issue in Python

Tags: python

When `a-b*i` becomes negative, why is `-8 % 5` `2`, rather than `3` or `-3`, when using Python 2.7.

```
a = 12
b = 5

for i in range(10):
    print a-b*i, (a-b*i) % b

12 2
7 2
2 2
-3 2
-8 2
-13 2
-18 2
-23 2
-28 2
-33 2
```

Comment: Note: it could not be 3, because -8 ≢ 3 (mod 5)

Comment: @spectras, thanks for the response and vote up. I am thinking like this, why not -8 = 5 * -1 + (-3)? And this is where my confusion comes from. Though result could be -3. :)

Your advice is appreciated.

Comment: Result could be either -3 or +2, indeed. Python chooses the result that has the sign of the right-hand operand while some other languages choose the result that has the sign of the left-hand operand.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it yourself using google calculator:

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=-8+%25+5

when you do Euclidian divison of a/n, you get a reminder. The whole deal should satisfy an equation 
`a = qn + r`
where q is a quotient, that belongs to Z ( integers from -inf to +inf)
So in your case

```
-8 = 5 * (-2) + 2
thus 
r = 2 = (-8) % 5
```

Comment: Thanks Stanley, but why not `-8 = 5 * -1 + (-3)`? And this is where my confusion comes from. Though result could be -3. :)

Comment: Hi Stanley, do you miss a link? :)

Comment: yep: -) from the Python docs: The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its second operand (or zero); In your example remainder would be (-3), which is negative. Also, Python enforces tis properties, abs(a%b) < abs(b) and, 0 <= r < b.

Comment: I believe you are getting the 2 because Python floors the quotient to negative infinity. 

Here are some examples: 

`# Per http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html`

`# Python floors quotient to negative infinity`

`import math`

`print (8 / 5) # Outputs: 1`

`print (-8 / 5) # Outputs: -2`

`print (-8.0 / 5.0) # Outputs: -1.6`

`print(math.floor(-8.0 / 5.0)) # Outputs: -2`

`print ( -8 % 5 )  # Outputs 2`

Comment: Thanks Stanley, vote up! :) For your comments "result with the same sign as its second operand (or zero)", in my sample, -8 % 5, the 2nd operand is 5? Correct? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, in my sample, -8 % 5, what is the negative infinity?